# Proguard with AWS (amazon service sdk) reutrn error code 1

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, proguard

Here is how I edit the proguard.txt. Are there any other thing I need to do before export the apk? As it return error code 1 now in proguard.

```
-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
-keep public class com.google.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.commons.logging.**               { *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.services.sqs.QueueUrlHandler  { *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.javax.xml.transform.sax.*     { public *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.javax.xml.stream.**           { *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.services.**.model.*Exception* { *; }
-keep class org.codehaus.**                             { *; }
-keepattributes Signature,*Annotation*

-dontwarn javax.xml.stream.events.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.impl.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.conn.scheme.**
-dontwarn com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.**
```

Here is the error

```
    [2014-07-08 18:43:49 - TuenmunTravel] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-07-08 18:43:49 - TuenmunTravel] Note: there were 1 duplicate class definitions.
[2014-07-08 18:43:49 - TuenmunTravel]       (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
[2014-07-08 18:43:49 - TuenmunTravel] Warning: com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2014-07-08 18:43:49 - TuenmunTravel] Warning: com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2014-07-08 18:43:49 - TuenmunTravel] Warning: com.amazonaws.DefaultRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2014-07-08 18:43:49 - TuenmunTravel] Warning: com.amazonaws.RequestClientOptions: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2014-07-08 18:43:49 - TuenmunTravel] Warning: com.amazonaws.auth.STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient
[2014-07-08 18:43:49 - TuenmunTravel] Warning: com.amazonaws.auth.STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient
[2014-07-08 18:43:49 - TuenmunTravel] Warning: com.amazonaws.auth.STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case , if I simply dowtwarn it will crash

I add the following to keep the class and so far it works

```
-keep class org.apache.commons.logging.**               { *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.services.sqs.QueueUrlHandler  { *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.javax.xml.transform.sax.*     { public *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.javax.xml.stream.**           { *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.services.**.model.*Exception* { *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.internal.**                   { *; }
-keep class org.codehaus.**                             { *; }
-keep class org.joda.convert.*                          { *; }
-keepattributes Signature,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.amazonaws.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your app works in debug mode, in spite of the listed missing classes, you can ignore the remaining warnings too:

```
-dontwarn com.amazonaws.**
```